# Fuel pressure regulator location?

Tags: honda, fuel-system, accord, fuel-pressure-regulator

I am trying to replace a fuel pressure regulator on my 2000 Honda Accord LX 3.0 engine. I bought the correct FPR. However, I am looking for the location near the engine. 1999 had it on the rail, but in 2000 it may be in a separate box by the firewall. I want to change it myself and I am searching for the location.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's on the fuel rail by the throttle body.

---

2000 Honda Accord LX 3.0 Sedan

> 1. Place a shop towel under the fuel pressure regulator, then relieve fuel pressure..
> 2. Disconnect the vacuum hose (A) and fuel return hose (B).
>
> Fig 1: Disconnecting Vacuum Hose & Fuel Return Hose
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Loosen the locking nut (C), and remove the fuel pressure regulator (D).
> 4. Apply clean engine oil to a new O-ring (E), and carefully install it into its proper position.
> 5. Install the fuel pressure regulator in the fuel joint. Turn it by hand until stops.
> 6. Turn the fuel pressure regulator (A) counterclockwise to set the angle as shown.
>
> Fig 2: Turning Fuel Pressure Regulator
>
> [image]
>
> 7. Tighten the locking nut to 29 N.m (3.0 kgf.m, 22 lbf.ft).